# Angular4 referencing a service inside a map operator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a service :

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
   constructor(private _convertor: Convertor)

   foo() {
      a = ["1", "2", "3"]
      return a.map(this.blah)
   }

   blah(s: string): number {
     return this_.convertor.parseInt(s)
   }

}
```

However, it keeps saying that `this` isn't defined. I replaced my `map` with a `for`, and it worked just fine. I also tried to use `_.map` which gave me the same result.
Any idea how to specify to the map what `this` it is supposed to use ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current context was lost due to the callback function, From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can preserve the current context by passing second arg to map function. So,

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
   constructor(private _convertor: Convertor)

   foo() {
      a = ["1", "2", "3"]
      return a.map(this.blah, this)
   }

   blah(s: string): number {
     return this._convertor.parseInt(s)
   }

}
```

and also it is `this._convertor.parseInt(s)` but not `this_.convertor.parseInt(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core/src/core";
import { Convertor } from "./Convertor"

export class AppService {
    constructor(private _convertor: Convertor)
    {

    }

   foo() {
      let a = ["1", "2", "3"]
      return a.map(this.blah)
   }

   blah(s: string): number {
     return this._convertor.parseInt(s)
   }

}
```